# Closed set on $\mathbb{R}^2$ written as disjoint union of sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed set. If $\gamma = \bigcup_{i\in\Lambda} U_i $ with $U_i\cap U_j = \emptyset$ $\forall i\neq j$, there exist $j\in\Lambda$ with $U_j$ being a closed set?

Comment: Take union of to disjoint closed disks, move the center of each disk to the other.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I didn't understand what is going to be $\gamma$ and $\{U_i\}$ in this example.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily true. Let $U_1$ be the closed unit disk with the right-half-boundary deleted. Let $U_2$ be the complement of the open unit disk with the left-half-boundary on the circle deleted. They are disjoint. Their union, $\gamma$, is $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is closed. But neither $U_1$ nor $U_2$ are closed.

Comment: @PranavChinmay Thank you! I wondering if it is also false if $U_i$ is an image of a curve $\gamma_i : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: You can decompose the real line as the disjoint union of subsets each of which is dense in the real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:
$$
{\mathbb R}= \coprod_{n\in {\mathbb Z}} [n, n+1).  
$$